# Polynomial Representation in Java

Tags: java

I want to represent a polynomial with the help of linked list. Here goes my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Multiply_Poly
{
    polynode head;
    Multiply_Poly()
    {
        head=null;
    }

    public void construct_poly(polynode head,float coeff,int exp)
    {
        if(head==null)
        {
            polynode newnode = new polynode(coeff,exp);
            head=newnode;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            polynode newnode = new polynode(coeff,exp);
            polynode temp = head;
            while(temp.next!=null)
                temp=temp.next;

            temp.next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
        }
    }

    public void show_poly(polynode head)
    {
        if(head==null)
            return;

        else
        {
            while(head.next!=null)
            {
                System.out.print("(" + head.coeff + ")" + "x^" + "(" + head.exp + ")" + "+");
                head=head.next;
            }

            System.out.print("(" + head.coeff + ")" + "x^" + "(" + head.exp + ")");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Multiply_Poly m = new Multiply_Poly();
        m.construct_poly(m.head,12,5);
        m.construct_poly(m.head,9,4);
        m.construct_poly(m.head,26,3);
        m.construct_poly(m.head,18,2);
        m.construct_poly(m.head,10,1);
        m.construct_poly(m.head,5,0);

        m.show_poly(m.head);
    }
}

class polynode
{
    float coeff;
    int exp;
    polynode next;

    polynode(float coeff,int exp)
    {
        this.coeff=coeff;
        this.exp=exp;
        next=null;
    }
}
```

I think my construct_poly function is not working. That's why show_poly function returns null. Is my else part in construct_poly is not written correctly ? What is my mistake ?

Comment: You have a naming conflict with `head`. Remove the `head` parameter from all methods.

Comment: The same thing happens when I replace head with any other paramenter @molbdnilo

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar Think about what happens when you assign a value to a function's parameter. Remove the `polynode` parameter. You should have `public void construct_poly(float coeff,int exp)`. And you should take a look at the chapter about classes and objects in your favourite Java book.

Comment: I think a better design would start with a Monomial class.  Once I had that united tested to perfection I'd create a Polynomial class that had a collection of Monomials.

Comment: Really Sorry @molbdnilo. It works fine when I replace head with another parameter. Ty:)

Comment: Why implement your own linked list when Java comes with many great collection classes? Let the well-tested Java library do the common stuff, and pay more attention to *your* logic. E.g. should you be able to add both `9x^5` and `7x^5` (same `exp`)? What should happen if they are added out-of-order, e.g. `2x^3 + 2x^1 + 2x^2`? Also, you should seriously consider using `double` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

In the construct_poly method in **if(head==null)** part just change

```
head=newnode; 
to this.head=newnode;
```

Reason for doing is that you want to refer to your class variable polynode head i.e. at the beginning of your linked list, but using only head(not          this.head) compiler refers it to local variable head passed as argument.

So we use     **this.head** to refer to class variable of calling object.

REMEMBER: Local variables always have higher priority than global variables.

Also there is no need of last line of else part i.e.

```
temp=newnode;
```

is not required.

After above changes your code runs perfectly fine.